# MVC 5 remove ViewModel's list element with checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a ViewModel with a list how can I remove the list elements using checkboxes? I generate checkboxes with a foreach in the edit action, but how can I get the checkboxes' value beside the ViewModel with HttpPost?

```
<dl>
     @foreach (var flower in Model.FlowerList)
     {
         <dt><input type="checkbox" id="@flower.Id" name="@flower.Id"/></dt>
         <dd>@flower.Name</dd>
     }
</dl>
```

With this code down I can get only the viewmodel's values, but not the checkboxes' because they are not part of the viewmodel.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public override ActionResult Edit(int id, BouquetViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(viewModel);
    }
    DataService.Update(viewModel);
    return RedirectToAction("Details/" + id);
}
```

Comment: could you please clarify your question. I don't understand what is your problem =/

Comment: I have have a form with the viemodel's values like the name etc and I generate chechboxes with the list item's ID for the viewmodel's flower list, I want that if I uncheck a checkbox after the submit I remove the unchecked items from the list. How can I reach the checkboxes which are not the part of the viewmodel in the post action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your giving each checkbox different `name` attribute so assuming you check the checkboxes with `flower.Id=4` and `flower.Id=8` then your form data is going to include `...4=on&8=on...` which is pretty useless

One option would be to use

```
@foreach (var flower in Model.FlowerList)
{
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedflowers" value="@flower.Id" /> // id not necessary
    @flower.Name</dd>
}
```

and then add a parameter to you method (assumes `flower.Id` is typeof `int`)

```
public override ActionResult Edit(int id, BouquetViewModel viewModel int[] SelectedFlowers)
```

and the parameter `SelectedFlowers` will contain a collection of the selected `Id`'s

However, since your using view models the better approach is to add a boolean property to the view model so you can bind a checkbox to it. You have not shown your models, but assuming they are

```
public class BouquetViewModel
{
  ....
  public List<FlowerViewModel> FlowerList { get; set; }
}

public class FlowerViewModel
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool IsSelected { get; set; } // add this
}
```

and then in the view (note you must use a `for` loop not a `foreach`loop)

```
for (int i = 0, i < Model.FlowerList.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FlowerList[i].ID)
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.FlowerList[i].IsSelected)
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FlowerList[i].IsSelected, Model.FlowerList[i].Name)
}
```

Then in the POST method you can access the selected items using

```
IEnumerable<FlowerViewModel> selectedFlowers = viewModel.FlowerList.Where(f => f.IsSelected);
```

Side note: No where in your POST method code do you indicate what your wanting to do with the selected ID's so its a little unclear exactly what your wanting to do.

Answer (score 0):

Only the checked options will be sent to controller. If you want to find the options which are not checked, you need to compare the original values against the posted values, then you will find the "not checked" options.

If you don't want to do that, you can use `@Html.CheckBox` or `@Html.CheckBoxFor`. In addition to rendering a check box input element, this method renders a hidden input element so that an unselected check box will return false.

Take a look at: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.checkbox(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Well yes, I see int the browser's Developer Tools what the it sends back to the server in the post, but how can I get those additional checkboxes' value, because they're not the part of the viewmodel.

Comment: Use the same query you've used to generate the options for the first time, `Model.FlowerList`. Then, compare that list against the new list, you will find the not checked options.